# All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error. This is the code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server_info` (
  `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The error I am receiving is this:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> This option conflicts with "`DEFAULT`". (near "`DEFAULT`" at position 79)
> SQL query.

MySQL documentation:

> #1171 - All parts of a `PRIMARY KEY` must be `NOT NULL`; if you need `NULL` in a key, use `UNIQUE` instead

Anyone knows what to change in the code above?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Either make `name` not null (and without a default value) or find another primary key

Comment: Remove the `DEFAULT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You must use 'not null' for primary keys. At name column, change DEFAULT NULL to NOT NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server_info` (
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I wouldn't define a DEFAULT for the primary key column either.

Comment: That's not necessary. PRIMARY KEY is already unique. Now that I'm looking at it more closely, the additional `KEY (name)` is not needed, since the PRIMARY KEY implicitly creates an index. Also [I don't recommend using MyISAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717).